# Expand Variables in a List Python

Tags: python, list

Need to know how to expand variable inside list element

```
  >>> one_more = "four"
  >>> var_names = ["one", "two", "three_<expand variable one_more>"]
```

should get something like

```
  ['one', 'two', 'three_four']
```

Comment: don't var_names[-1] = var_names[-1]+one_more do the trick? If you need a more general answer you need to be more specific

Comment: How would you do it without a list?

Comment: This question is a little vague in the sense of what exactly you're trying to achieve. For that **specific** input/output combination either the below answer or the one in the comments above will suffice, but they will not work in any kind of general case.

Answer (score 2):

Very basic:

```
In [1]: a="four"    
In [2]: b="five"
In [3]: ['one', 'two', 'three_%s' % a]
Out[3]: ['one', 'two', 'three_four']
```

You could also join a list a variables:

```
In [5]: ['one', 'two', 'three_%s' % '_'.join((a,b))]
Out[5]: ['one', 'two', 'three_four_five']
```

Here is the same solution with str.format:

```
In [6]: ['one', 'two', 'three_{}'.format('_'.join((a,b)))]
Out[6]: ['one', 'two', 'three_four_five']
```

Comment: You should probably use `str.format()` instead since using `%` for string formatting has been depreciated.

Comment: @aruisdante, `str.format` creates a readable python code, but for new comers from C and other languages the `%s` style is very familiar.

Comment: @aruisdante please don't say it's deprecated: it really isn't.

Comment: Plus using `format` allows you to do keyword-based replace trivially, which might wind up being more what the OP wants, hard to tell from his question.

Comment: @DanielRoseman You're right, I could have sworn in the docs it said *depreciated*, but it merely says *discouraged*. I'd edit my comment but it's been more than 5 minutes :(

Comment: The confusion over '%' formatting isn't helped by old statements from e.g. Guido (see http://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html) saying that the plan was to deprecate that syntax while other sources are just as emphatic that it's never going away.

Comment: @aruisdante, you can do keyword replace really easily with % as well: `'%(x)d + %(y)d' % locals()` or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you want to do a string replacement within a list. Here is an example fits your requirement.

```
one_more = "four"
var_names = ["one", "two", "three_<var>"]

print [x.replace("<var>", one_more) for x in var_names]

>>> ["one", "two", "three_four"]
```

If you want to have replace more than one pattern in one shot, you can do this:

```
a = "AA"
b = "BB"
var_names = ["one", "two", "three_$a", "four_$b"]

def batch_replace(str, lookup):
   for pattern in lookup:
      replacement = lookup[pattern]
      str = str.replace(pattern, replacement)
   return str

print [batch_replace(x, {"$a": a, "$b": b}) for x in var_names] 

>>> ["one", "two", "three_AA", "four_BB"]
```